# How to divide string to single chars and put them in the array?

Tags: java

I realise it's pretty basic.

I need to ask user for an string input. Then I divide string to single char array and print it in a console. I have to ignore spaces

Tried this but when I input "this is test string" as output I get only {t h i s}

```
    String tekst;        
    Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Wpisz tekst");
    tekst = odczyt.next();
    int iloscZnakow = tekst.length();
    char tablica[] = new char[iloscZnakow];
    tablica = tekst.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tablica));
```

Comment: Is this homework? Why would you need to divide the string to single characters?

Comment: I recommend writing the names of your variables, types, etc. in English. In Polish it really does not look good, neither in any other language than English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace odczyt.next(); with odczyt.nextLine();

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method of `String` class.

Comment: ye I know that, however when I input "this is test string" as output I get only {t h i s}

Comment: @Xylian you need to the nextLine() instead of the next() **word**